# scrolling list in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, frontend, vuetify.js

Here's my Vuetify code for using list:

```
<v-list>
    <v-list-tile
            v-for="user in users"
            :key="user.id"
            avatar
            @click=""
    >

        <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title v-text="user.name"></v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile-content>

        <v-btn icon>
            <v-icon>edit</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
    </v-list-tile>
</v-list>
```

The problem is, that I have over 100 users and the list is not scrollable by default. Is there any trait that helps with it?

Comment: Just style the v-list to have a fixed max-height and overflow-y auto?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I achieved this by giving the style of `max-height: 100px` and adding vuetify class `overflow-y-auto` to `<v-list></v-list>`

For eg:

```
<v-list
       style="max-height: 100px"
       class="overflow-y-auto"
>
    <template 
             v-for="user in users"
    >
        <v-list-tile
                    :key="user.id"
                    avatar
                    @click=""
        >
            <v-list-tile-content>
                <v-list-tile-title v-text="user.name"></v-list-tile-title>
            </v-list-tile-content>
            <v-btn icon>
                <v-icon>edit</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
        </v-list-tile>        
    </template>    
</v-list>
```

Comment: This is outdated info. The appropriate class is `overflow-y-auto` now instead of `scroll-y`

Answer (score 30):

For vuetify 2.0 the helper class 'scroll-y' is changed to **'overflow-y-auto'**.
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/releases (Just Ctrl+F 'scroll-y')
So use.

```html
<v-list style="max-height: 100px" class="overflow-y-auto">
```

Comment: Do you by any mean know if it is supposed to work on mobile? I ask it because it works for me on desktop and devtools mobile but on real mobile the body scrolls also.

Comment: I have verified it working on IPHONE 7 Safari Browser. Can you share a CodePen so that I can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Weird, I tested on iPhone 8 and X safari and not working.

Comment: Is there no Vuetify-styled scrollbar? I just see a plain looking browser scrollbar as opposed to a material design one

Answer (score 18):

For the record, you don't actually need to use a `style` attribute at all, you can do it with the `overflow-y-auto` class and a `max-height` prop:

```html
<v-list class="overflow-y-auto" max-height="400">
```

Working with `Vue 2.6.10` and `Vuetify 2.0.0`, might not work for [newer Vuetify 2 versions](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-list/#props).

Comment: Is there a way to avoid using a fixed height?

Comment: How would it know when to scroll and when to overflow if it doesn't have a fixed height?  That seems like conflicting requirements.  Depending on what you mean, you could potentially use a height like `100vh` to make it the same height as the viewport (or, say, `80vh` to leave space for margin).

Comment: Both `max-height="400"` and `style="max-height: 400"` behaves the same.  However `max-height="80vh"` doesn't seem to work, where `style="max-height: 80vh"` does.

Answer (score 3):

The solution using `class` and `style` did not work for me. The vertical scroll appeared outside the list and was applied to the div that was wrapping it.

This solution did work perfect:

```html
<v-list three-line max-height="400px" class="overflow-y-auto">
```